# How to export varnish response times

Tags: varnish

We are looking to measure the performance of the our varnish server in terms of response times. We already have https://github.com/jonnenauha/prometheus_varnish_exporter but as far as I can tell response times is not a metric measured by `varnishstat`. Effectively we want to do what `varnishhist` does but in kibana or graphana. Any ideas?

Separately, the fact that looking in the web for this has not yielded a solution worries me. Are we trying to measure the wrong thing or at the wrong place maybe? How do people generally monitor their response times when using varnish? (which nginx for examples you track logs with EFK and pull out stats this way).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We figured this out. You can use varnishncsa to create and customise logs which you can then get into ES. I believe the correct time to use if you need response time (rather than time to first byte), is adding `%{VSL:Timestamp:Resp}x` in the log format and use the middle of the 3 numbers it prints.